# Service is terminated when click on TableView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have the following problem. When I press the `Button`, I execute a `Service` that parses an html page and puts the results in a table. When I click on the table, while the `Service` is running, the `Service` will be terminated.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Here is my controller class:

```
public class ProxySearchController implements Initializable {

       private Scene                             scene;
       @FXML
       private Button                            btn_refresh;
       @FXML
       private TableView<ProxyResult>            tbl_results;
       @FXML
       private ProgressBar                       pb_search;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, String>  column_ip;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, Integer> column_port;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, Locale>  column_locale;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, String>  column_anonymity;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, Boolean> column_google;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, Boolean> column_https;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, String>  column_lastchecked;
       @FXML
       private TableColumn<ProxyResult, Long>    column_response;
    
       private ObservableList<ProxyResult>       data   = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
       /*
        * (non-Javadoc)
        * 
        * @see javafx.fxml.Initializable#initialize(java.net.URL, java.util.ResourceBundle)
        */
       @Override
       public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    
          tbl_results.setItems(data);
          tbl_results.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    
          Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
          // add listner to your tableview selecteditemproperty
          tbl_results.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ProxyResult>() {
    
             @Override
             public void changed(ObservableValue observable, ProxyResult oldValue, ProxyResult newValue) {
    
                ObservableList<TablePosition> posList = tbl_results.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
                int old_r = -1;
                StringBuilder clipboardString = new StringBuilder();
                for (TablePosition p : posList) {
                   int r = p.getRow();
                   int c = p.getColumn();
                   Object cell = tbl_results.getColumns().get(c).getCellData(r);
                   if (cell == null)
                      cell = "";
                   if (old_r == r)
                      clipboardString.append('\t');
                   else if (old_r != -1)
                      clipboardString.append('\n');
                   clipboardString.append(cell);
                   old_r = r;
                }
                final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(clipboardString.toString());
                Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
             }
          });
    
          column_ip.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, String>("ip"));
          column_port.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, Integer>("port"));
          column_locale.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, Locale>("locale"));
          column_anonymity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, String>("anonymity"));
          column_google.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, Boolean>("google"));
          column_https.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, Boolean>("https"));
          column_lastchecked.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, String>("lastChecked"));
          column_response.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProxyResult, Long>("responseTime"));
       }
    
       public void handleSearchButton(ActionEvent event) {
    
          Service<Void> searchWorker = new SearchProxyWorker(pb_search, data);
    
          searchWorker.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    
             @Override
             public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
    
                System.out.println("Tadaaa");
             }
    
          });
    
          searchWorker.start();
       }
    
       /**
        * Set the current scene.
        * 
        * @param scene A scene
        */
       public void setScene(Scene scene) {
    
          this.scene = scene;
       }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error when the service stops ?

Comment: So i've added a setOnFail Event to the Service. And now i became the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5

Comment: Now it work with the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850191/why-am-i-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-on-javafx)