# Update UI from another Thread (after time)

Tags: java, javafx

Im trying to update the primaryStage after a set amount of time. This gives me: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;`
I've been searching for a solution on StackOverflow and I found some people suggest using

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable ...)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17851019/5314214

But still I can't figure out how to make it work after a set amount of time.

My code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update(primaryStage);
        timer.cancel();
    }
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(
    new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> update(primaryStage));
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, 400
);
```

Anytime you want to modify your stage from another thread you need to do it through `Platform.runLater` as only the `FX application thread` is allowed to do it, indeed `JavaFX` has not been designed to be used by concurrent threads to prevent bugs hard to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use a `PauseTransition`. The benefit is that it you don't have to use `Platform.runLater()`

```
  PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(400));
  pauseTransition.setOnFinished(e -> updateStage());
  pauseTransition.playFromStart();
```